# How to call a variable inside a function then use it in another function

Tags: python

im doing a little project for myself to understand the function, if statement in python. i want to call the "name" inside the user function and use it in jungle function.

```
def user():
    global name
    name = raw_input("Whats your name?")

def jungle():

    print name, "Please, Select your Enemy"
    print '\n'.join(jungle_enemy)

    enemy = raw_input('> ')

   if enemy == "1":
        print "The Lion Will eat you alive."
        game_over()
        exit_countdown()

    elif enemy == "2":
        print "The Jaguar will tear you apart."
        game_over()
        exit_countdown()

    elif enemy == "3":
        print "The Snake will eat you whole."
        game_over()
        exit_countdown()

    else:
        try_again("Are You Noob? \nNone of the Choice!")
        jungle()
```

when i run this code. it gives me an error.
NameError : global name 'name' is not define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are a bad idea in general. Better pass the variable to whoever needs it:

```
def user():
    return raw_input("Whats your name?")

def jungle(name):
    print name, "Please, Select your Enemy"
    # etc.
```

and then call the functions like this

```
username = user()
jungle(username)
```

If you *have* to use global names, you need to use the `global` statement in all the functions that use that variable - so you need to add `global name` at the start of `jungle()`. But don't do that. See where global variables have taken JavaScript - you don't want to do that in Python.